# ActiveAdmin show, edit, and delete actions in custom models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a rails 3 application which uses the ActiveAdmin gem.

If I do not customizes my models, 3 actions are enabled in each line of my model : show, edit, delete

But if I customizes my model, the actions disappear.

Model not customized  showing the actions (users.rb) :

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'Users_full' do
  menu :parent => 'Users'
end
```

Custom model not showing actions (companies.rb) :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :name
    column :url
  end

  csv do
    column :name
    column :url
  end
end
```

Is there a way to get actions in customized models ? I have already tried to add : `actions :all`, `config.batch_actions = true` and `action_item` to my companies.rb file but nothing change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the [`actions`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L238-L259), like:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :name
  column :url
  actions
end
```

You're defining the index page's content, and that content includes the actions-if you omit them, they won't show up.

Comment: As the [docs](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/25884a5d2852f833cdc893d55d7c231610d98847/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md#defining-columns) explain, you can use `actions` instead of the longer `default_actions`

Comment: Thanks, I had added `default_actions` before the index block.